# Magento 2 calculate product price against user input

Tags: magento, attributes, magento2, product

I am currently trying to implement some extra product price attribute which will take user input and calculate the price according to that. Tried with price attribute but not working. Any idea how to do it, as new in magento unable to fix that. Please note height and width are input type text, a user can add any value

[image]

To achieve this, i have created a set of attributes in admin section,
[image]

From the front end trying to calculate the price,

```
require([
        'jquery','Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils','jquery/ui','Magento_Catalog/js/price-box'
    ], function($,priceUtils,priceBox){

        "use strict";
        var priceBoxes = $('[data-role=priceBox]');
        $('.product-custom-optionval').change(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();

            if (value === '') { 
                $(this).val(0);
                updatePriceOnChange(0, $(this).attr('data-attr-id'));                            
                return;
            }
            disableAddToCartBtn('#product_addtocart_form');
            calculatePrice($(this));
            enableAddToCartBtn('#product_addtocart_form');
        });
    ****** But after calculating the price what will my approach to update product price, please help *******
```

Comment: Plz describe exactly with the code you have tried to achieve this and your exact problem. Regards.

Comment: @RohitRai bro, I don't have any idea how to start with. Thant's why trying to get some idea

Comment: @RohitRai please check the updated comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HI for this you can do something like

- Create custom module
- Define custom controller
- whenever user puts the input in the height and width
- Send those parameters to the controller along with the product id  and qty
- Do your calculations there on basis of your logic and return response
- upadte the price in the div on basis of the response
- than when user hits add to cart , listen before add to cart event and upadte the cart item price with the new price of your calculations
- rest magento will do itself

hope that will help you somehwere

Comment: Thanks for the details sir. Is there any way to create "Custom options" and depend on the user input the price will calculate

Comment: there is not any feature in Magento like this , but the thing is the user can put any value in the height and width options , otherwise you can use the configurable products . Thanks

Comment: hi @rohit, I have a custom attribute code "pc_price_per_unit_area". How i can get value in product details page

Comment: Ok, I am solidly following these steps, to achieve this logic.., but there is one thing I dont understand., in last steps.
How do I get Input data in observer ? How can I pass input data from input to Observer?